# DocuSign attachment optional not required in php api

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way how to make attachments optional

```
$attachment2 = new Text([
            'document_id' => '1',
            'page_number' => '8',
            'x_position' => "451",
            'y_position' => "307",
            'access_control' => "attachment2",
            'attachment_id' => "1",
            'attachment_type' => "",
            'data' => null,
            'label' => "attachment2",
            'name' => "attachment2",
            'remote_url' => null,
            'tab_label' => "Attachment 0cabbf65-8853-4651-a5a5-122d36adf439",
            'height' => "10",
            'width' => "10",
            'required' => "false"
        ]);
```

I am using Laravel php api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Attachment tabs you use:

```
'optional' => "true"
```

For Text tabs you use

```
'required' => "false"
```

Sorry for the inconsistency, but that's how you do it

Comment: For attachment, any special class and code are available can you please provide me a sample code I have use new Text([]) ;

You can see above code

Comment: You need to use new SignerAttachment([]) instead. Most things are very similar. the Tabs object has an array called SignerAttachmentTabs

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-php-client/blob/master/src/Model/SignerAttachment.php

Comment: Hi Inbar Gazit please have a look 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76556268/template-color-and-design

Comment: I have created on a template in which color and design change from the original design
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2snEU.png
and the original design is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAcdk.png